# Faulty D Dependency Logic in SCons

Tags: python, regex, import, d, scons

I've tracked down a bug in the dependency logic for D sources in SCons.

The [`self.cre` regexp `import\s+(?:\[a-zA-Z0-9_.\]+)\s*(?:,\s*(?:\[a-zA-Z0-9_.\]+)\s*)*;` in `SCons.Scanner.D`](https://bitbucket.org/per_nordlow/scons/src/7e4dd9c8304d8f197c0261df4ff18423f02775d9/src/engine/SCons/Scanner/D.py?at=default#cl-50) doesn't cover patterns such as...

```
import IMPORT_PATH : SYMBOL;
```

...only:

```
import IMPORT_PATH;
```

Same with the [`self.cre2` regexp `(?:import\s)?\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)\s*(?:,|;)` two lines later](https://bitbucket.org/per_nordlow/scons/src/7e4dd9c8304d8f197c0261df4ff18423f02775d9/src/engine/SCons/Scanner/D.py?at=default#cl-52).

I believe both the `self.cre` and `self.cre2` regexps need to be fixed; but I don't quite understand how they are related. My guess is that `self.cre` matches the whole import statements and `self.cre2` matches parts of them. Am I correct? If so `self.cre2` needs to be corrected to handle cases such as:

```
import X, Y, Z;
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix the regexps so that they handle these cases?

My first try is to change

```
p = 'import\s+(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)\s*(?:,\s*(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)\s*)*;'
```

to

```
p = 'import\s+(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)\s*(?:,\s*(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)(?:\s*:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)??\s*)*;'
```

I've tried debugging this but in vain.

Python:

```
import re
p = 'import\s+(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)\s*(?:,\s*(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)\s*)*;'

re.match(p, "import first;") # match
re.match(p, "import first : f;") # no match

p2 = 'import\s+(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)\s*(?:,\s*(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)(?:\s*:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)??\s*)*;'

re.match(p2, "import first;") # match
re.match(p2, "import first : f;") # no match but should match
re.match(p2, "import first : f, second : g;") # no match but should match
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short Answer

To handle all the cases you have outlined, try the following twist on your changes to the (`self.cre`) pattern:

```
import\s+(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)\s*(?:(?:\s+:\s+[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+\s*)?(?:,\s*(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)(?:\s*:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)??\s*)*)*;
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/yYg4_-DLNSnvcxkY)

## Digging Deeper

### self.cre vs. self.cre2

Yes, the [`find_include_names`](https://bitbucket.org/per_nordlow/scons/src/7e4dd9c8304d8f197c0261df4ff18423f02775d9/src/engine/SCons/Scanner/D.py?at=default#cl-63) method...

```
def find_include_names(self, node):
    includes = []
    for i in self.cre.findall(node.get_text_contents()):
        includes = includes + self.cre2.findall(i)
    return includes
```

...confirms the relationship between `self.cre` and `self.cre2` that you guessed: the former matches entire import statements, and the latter matches (and captures) modules therein.  (Note the middle `(`...`)` *capture* group in `self.cre2` vs. `(?:`...`)` *non*-capture groups elsewhere throughout `self.cre` and `self.cre2`.)

### self.cre

Picking up [where your Python snippet left off](http://ideone.com/RSNlbl)...

```
import re

import1 = "import first;"
import2 = "import first : f;"
import3 = "import first : f, second : g;"


p = 'import\s+(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)\s*(?:,\s*(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)\s*)*;'

pm1 = re.match(p, import1) # match
if pm1 != None:
    print "p w/ import1 => " + pm1.group(0)

pm2 = re.match(p, import2) # no match
if pm2 != None:
    print "p w/ import2 => " + pm2.group(0)


p2 = 'import\s+(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)\s*(?:,\s*(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)(?:\s*:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)??\s*)*;'

p2m1 = re.match(p2, import1) # match
if p2m1 != None:
    print "p2 w/ import1 => " + p2m1.group(0)

p2m2 = re.match(p2, import2) # no match but should match
if p2m2 != None:
    print "p2 w/ import2 => " + p2m2.group(0)

p2m3 = re.match(p2, import3) # no match but should match
if p2m3 != None:
    print "p2 w/ import3 => " + p2m3.group(0)
```

..., we get the following expected output for `p` and `p2` attempts to match the import statements:

```
p w/ import1 => import first;
p2 w/ import1 => import first;
```

Now consider `p2prime`, wherein I have made [changes to arrive at the pattern I suggested](http://ideone.com/BVB8Mp) above:

```
import re

import1 = "import first;"
import2 = "import first : f;"
import3 = "import first : f, second : g;"
import4 = "import first, second, third;"

p2prime = 'import\s+(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)\s*(?:(?:\s+:\s+[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+\s*)?(?:,\s*(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)(?:\s*:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)??\s*)*)*;'

p2pm1 = re.match(p2prime, import1) # match
if p2pm1 != None:
    print "p2prime w/ import1 => " + p2pm1.group(0)

p2pm2 = re.match(p2prime, import2) # now a match
if p2pm2 != None:
    print "p2prime w/ import2 => " + p2pm2.group(0)

p2pm3 = re.match(p2prime, import3) # now a match
if p2pm3 != None:
    print "p2prime w/ import3 => " + p2pm3.group(0)

p2pm4 = re.match(p2prime, import4) # now a match
if p2pm4 != None:
    print "p2prime w/ import4 => " + p2pm4.group(0)
```

With the updated pattern (`p2prime`) we get the following desired output for its attempts to match the import statements:

```
p2prime w/ import1 => import first;
p2prime w/ import2 => import first : f;
p2prime w/ import3 => import first : f, second : g;
p2prime w/ import4 => import first, second, third;
```

This is a pretty lengthy and involved pattern: so I would not be surprised to find opportunities to fine tune it further; but it does what you want and should provide a solid basis for fine tuning.

### self.cre2

For `self.cre2`, similarly try the following pattern:

```
(?:import\s)?\s*(?:([a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)(?:\s+:\s+[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+\s*)?)\s*(?:,|;)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/fPsB0j5VE_qHLK1M)

Keep in mind, however, that the since [D's `<module> : <symbol>` selective imports](http://dlang.org/module.html) are just that – selective, capturing the module names in selective imports may not be what you ultimately need (e.g. vs. capturing the module and selected symbol names).  As I similarly explained regarding the `self.cre` regexp I suggested, further fine tuning where warranted should not be difficult.

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work at https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/pull-request/215/handle-all-variants-of-d-imports/diff